# using xml as database in php

Tags: php, xml, database

I heard xml is used as database, can anybody give me a simple tip or link to tutorial  how to store some information in database ? what is the best use of xml on php realted to data things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is not supposed to be used as a database but as a way to transport data in an application agnostic way. For example, say you have many RSS feeds in Google Reader and you want to add them into Thunderbird. You will export them from Google Reader in the XML format, and then import that XML file into Thunderbird. Both applications will know how to read and write from the XML and how to use the information (the RSS feeds) in it.

If you want to store information in a useful way that, for example, lets you organize and search through it, you will need a full fledged database. Some good ones are [Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com) and [Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/). Both of those work well with PHP and have extensive tutorials to begin with, all easily accessible via any search engine.

Comment: RSSFeed is a URL, so I assume you just need to pass a list of strings from one app to another? Then won't comma separated format do the job?

Comment: @Tegiri, right, but I'm referring to OPML: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPML

Comment: I never understand why people constantly ACCEPT lame-ass answers that simply say that "Nope, what you want to do is impossible (stupid, hard, different, etc.)"  Such a response is NOT an answer, but a sign of laziness and or close-mindedness...  I'd rescind this Accept if I was the OP and realize where there is a will there is a way... not to mention that this answer is just plain WRONG.

Answer (score 6):

I'm gonna throw my hat in, simply because I am working on a personal project that does in fact use XML as it's storage mechanism. Notice, I didn't call it a database. It's not a database, at least in the way most would define it. As expressed in an article I read recently, XML is not data oriented, it's *document* oriented.

In my case, I'm building a simple OO php/XML resume site for my girlfriend. I am using an XML file to store the content. I chose this mainly because it's small, lightweight, interchangeable, and easy to read. Initially, I thought I could just provide the XML to her, and she could fill in the blanks. XML is straightforward enough to allow a laymen to do that.

As I continued, I realized that it wasn't very difficult to throw in an admin type interface where she could simply enter values in a form and update the resume that way.

Since the site is not really a web site, but a web *document*, XML works well here and nicely separates content.

Of course, I could have used JSON as well, and I may in fact adapt things to handle either JSON or XML, but I decided to use XML initially simply out of familiarity, and (this is arguable) that I assumed it would be easier for a laymen to parse when entering content.

Comment: I will likely release something at some point after I'm done, but it's not currently fit for public consumption.

Comment: what a lovely gesture to your girlfriend - are you still together?

Comment: Wow. Memories. In fact I am about to work on a new version since she will be looking for work soon. We will have been married three years this September. New version is angular based so the XML thing has seen better days.

Answer (score 2):

You can answer this question yourself after reading this very entertaining article by one of Stackoverflow founders:
[**Back to Basics** by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of the responses I got to my question ["Is there a simple, flat, XML-based query-able data storage solution?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95606/is-there-a-simple-flat-xml-based-query-able-data-storage-solution) on the Programmers.StackExchange Site.

It's a mixed bag.  SimpleXML is great with PHP, but there is a lot of FUD when it comes to [XML query languages and implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database#XML_Databases_with_database_APIs_.28XQJ.2C_XML:DB.2C_RESTful.29)..

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Fanis said, if you want something lightweight then I strongly recommend [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)